# Is prion a term used to describe the normal form of the protein as well as the disease causing form?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, terminology, protein-structure, prion

I've been reading my textbook and it refers to prions as a normal protein with a helpful function but it can turn into a disease causing form. However, I look in my other textbook and it refers to the word prion as solely being a disease causing protein.

I'd like to know which is the correct definition. Ie. Would I be correct in saying "The prion protein is normally involved in synaptic transmission but can turn into a disease causing form"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The normal isoform of the protein is called PrP<sup>C</sup>, which stands for *cellular prion protein*, while the infectious isoform is called PrP<sup>SC</sup>, which stands for *scrapie prion protein*.

According to Riesner (2003):

> The biochemical properties of the prion protein which is the major, if not only, component of the prion are outlined in detail. **PrP** is a host-encoded protein which exists as **PrP<sup>C</sup>** (cellular) in the non-infected host, and as **PrP<sup>Sc</sup>** (scrapie) as the major component of the scrapie infectious agent. (emphasis mine)

If you search for *"cellular prion protein"* you're gonna find several papers that use the name prion protein to the normal isoform. Some examples:

- [Prado, M., Alves-Silva, J., Magalhães, A., Prado, V., Linden, R., Martins, V. and Brentani, R. (2004). PrPc on the road: trafficking of the cellular prion protein. Journal of Neurochemistry, 88(4), pp.769-781](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14756798).
- [Ramljak, S. (2008). Physiological function of the cellular prion protein (PrPc_1hnc). 1st ed. Berlin: Logos-Verl](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=T_mA1aOlk5MC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=prpc%20cellular&source=bl&ots=GIaDVA2wNU&sig=CdiUrSf2QfBbJLtvaIdCTwKvg7U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvvKKS54nUAhXLF5QKHdlSDZMQ6AEISDAG#v=snippet&q=the%20cellular&f=false).
- [Pantera, B., Bini, C., Cirri, P., Paoli, P., Camici, G., Manao, G. and Caselli, A. (2009). PrP<sup>c</sup> activation induces neurite outgrowth and differentiation in PC12 cells: role for caveolin-1 in the signal transduction pathway. Journal of Neurochemistry, 110(1), pp.194-207](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1471-4159.2009.06123.x/pdf).
- [Martins, V., Mercadante, A., Cabral, A., Freitas, A. and Castro, R. (2017). Insights into the physiological function of cellular prion protein](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0100-879X2001000500005).

And many others.

Therefore, following this nomenclature, the answer to your question (*"Would I be correct in saying 'The prion protein is normally involved in synaptic transmission but can turn into a disease causing form'?"*) is **yes**. The difference is the adjective: cellular or scrapie.

Finally, pay attention to this: you have two different questions here. In the title you say *"Is **prion** a term used..."*, but in the last paragraph you say *""Is the **prion protein** normally involved in..."*. As extensively discussed in the [other answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/60024/24284), the term *prion* alone (instead of *prion protein*) is normally used only when referring to the abnormal isoform. More on that here: https://www.cdc.gov/prions/pdfs/public-health-impact.pdf

Source: [Detlev Riesner; Biochemistry and structure of PrPC and PrPSc. Br Med Bull 2003; 66 (1): 21-33](https://academic.oup.com/bmb/article/66/1/21/284815/Biochemistry-and-structure-of-PrPC-and-PrPSc).

Comment: This is also a fairly good review that outlines some of the history of the research and how the naming came to be. [THE PUBLIC HEALTH IMPACT OF PRION DISEASES](https://www.cdc.gov/prions/pdfs/public-health-impact.pdf)

Comment: @AMR Thanks, I just linked that in the question.

Answer (score 9):

If we are considering prions in general, I disagree with the answer supplied by Gerardo Furtado.

Here is a definition taken from [an article by Susan Lindquist](http://m.genesdev.cshlp.org/content/23/19/2320.long?view=long&pmid=19797769):

> [Prions are]...self-perpetuating and heritable protein conformations that cause multiple phenotypes,
>   represent an unusual mechanism of information transfer that occurs via protein instead of nucleic acid.

Compare Wikipedia:

> Prions are infectious agents...

If a prion is self-perpetuating or infectious then the normal form of such a protein is not a prion. In yeast the term prion is used to refer to the infectious form of a protein in a formal genetic sense. For example the [*PSI<sup>+</sup>*] prion was discovered as a genetic element and  then subsequently found to be associated with the translation termination factor Sup35, a protein with a known cellular role. All yeast strains have Sup35 protein but only certain strains contain and transmit the prion form of this protein. So [*PSI<sup>+</sup>*] is referred to as the prion form of the protein.

The problem with interpreting the language used to describe the TSE prions is that they were discovered because of their prion activity so the normal form is referred to as prion protein (as far as I am aware the function of the normal form isn't known). This doesn't mean that this form of the protein IS a prion, merely that this protein is associated with the original prion phenomenon so is called 'prion protein'.

Comment: If you didn't truncate your Wikipedia quote: "Prions are infectious agents composed entirely of a protein material that **can** fold in multiple, structurally abstract ways"

Comment: And if you didn't truncate your Lindquist quote: "Prion proteins can assume **at least two** conformations"

Comment: I don't understand why you think that makes a difference. If a prion is the infectious form ('infectious agent') of a protein that can fold in different ways, that doesn't mean that the non-infectious form is a prion. A cell which contains only the normal form of a prion-forming protein doesn't contain any prions since it contains no infectious agents.

Comment: Yes, Lindquist refers to proteins that can form prions as 'prion proteins' but not as prions. Just like the cellular form  of the TSE agent is called 'prion protein'. But please, write your own answer.

Comment: I don't need to. I just need to upvote the correct answer and downvote the wrong one.

Comment: @OrangeDog I don't know why you're so emphatic that this answer is incorrect. The [original definition from Prusiner](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/216/4542/136) states *...a new term "prion" is proposed to denote a small proteinaceous infectious particle...*. Clearly that definition precludes its use for referring to normal proteins, especially since it predates any linkage between the infectious particle and it's normal, non-infectious variant. As Alan Boyd said, there is a distinction between prion and prion protein.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado The title also poses the following question (which is the one you answered **yes** to): *Is prion a term used to describe the normal form of the protein as well as the disease causing form?* The answer to this question should be no, which is presumably where the disagreement arises (though I can only speak for myself). Again, there is a distinction between a prion and what was later called the prion protein.

Comment: @canadianer OP is clearly not asking if the term **alone** is used to describe the normal isoform. Anyway, I'll edit my answer to make clear I'm answering his second question.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado There are two explicit questions and it seems that you answered one and this post the other. Anyways, you've got my upvote after your edit.

Comment: @canadianer is correct in referencing Prusiner, as he is credited with the nomenclature and usage.

Comment: @canadianer Ok, I'll edit my answer again (hopefully for the last time) to make it clear that the name cannot be used **alone**.

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia definition of prions is quite clear I think:

> Prions are infectious agents composed entirely of a protein material
>   that can fold in multiple, structurally abstract ways, at least one of
>   which is transmissible to other prion proteins, leading to disease in
>   a manner that is epidemiologically comparable to the spread of viral
>   infection.

Your definition: "The prion protein is normally involved in synaptic transmission but can turn into a disease causing form" it is misleading. First, it sounds like there is a protein called prion that is involved in synaptic transmission, which is not true. Prions are a subset of the group proteins. Moreover, not all the prions are derived from proteins involved in the synaptic transmission. Prions have been found in other organisms like bacteria and fungi, so there is little to do with synaptic transmission there. The wiki page I have linked is full of links to the related literature, start there your journey!